# How to get scope of store in grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3

I wrote my Ajax in init component and I am getting all the require data in `this.store`.
But I am not getting scope of store in grid where i defined. Since I am closing the bracket of Ajax Success I am not. what is the correct way to do.
My Code is :

```
initComponent: function() {
    this.fields = [];
    this.columns = [];
    this.data = [];
    this.store = [];
    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'XML/1Cohart.xml',
                        scope: this,
                        timeout: global_constants.TIMEOUT,
                        method: "GET", 
                        disableCaching: true,
                        failure: function(response) {
                            utils.showOKErrorMsg(sdisMsg.ajaxRequestFailed);
                        },
                        success: function(response) {
                            var datas = response.responseXML;
                            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("HEADER"), function(header) {
                                this.buildField(header);
                                this.buildColumn(header);
                            }, this);
                            Ext.each(datas.getElementsByTagName("G"), function (columnData) {
                              this.buildData(columnData);
                                this.fieldLength = this.fields.length;
                                this.record = [];
                                for (i = 0; i < this.fieldLength; i++) {
                                    //debugger;
                                    var fieldName = this.fields[i].name
                                    this.record[i] = columnData.getAttribute(fieldName);
                                }
                                this.data.push(this.record);                 
                            }, this);
                            this.store = new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                                fields : this.fields
                            });
                            this.store.loadData(this.data); // Getting correct data in this.store
                        },
                    });
```

In same init component in east panel i defined grid. for which column is coming but store is not getting.

Grid code is

```
          {
            xtype: 'panel',
            region: "east",
            header: true,
            collapsible: true,
            autoScroll: true,
            //columnWidth: 0.5,
            width: "30%",
            hideBorders: true,
            split: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: "Search Result",
                height:500,
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'grid',
                    itemid: 'ABC_GRID',
                    store : this.store,
                    autoHeight: true,
                    sm: new Ext.grid.CheckboxSelectionModel({singleSelect:true}),
                    frame: true,
                    columns : this.columns,
                }]

            }]
```

Comment: `initComponent` is called on which component? Where your grid code is defined?

Comment: Grid is also in init component. I am losing the scope of `this.store` in Ajax success only.

Answer (score 0):

After loading the data in `this.store` get the grid and reconfigure its store

```
   Ext.ComponentQuery.query("#ABC_GRID")[0].reconfigure(this.store);
```

**For ExtJs 3**

We need use `Ext.getCmp()` as `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` is not supported. Need to define `id` property of grid as `id:ABC_GRID`.

```
Ext.getCmp("ABC_GRID").reconfigure(this.store)
```

Comment: So where I declare my grid there should I leave blank in store ?

Comment: Sorry I tried but its not working. Not even stop at debugger.

Comment: Ext.ComponentQuery.query is not available in EXTJS 3.

Comment: See my updated answer for extjs 3.No need to define store in grid declaration.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than calling This.store you can call grid.getview().getStore(), you will get the store of the grid where you want to load the data.